# Нужно ли как-то особо настраивать сервер для безостановочного парсинга?

Tags: php, nginx

У меня на сервере работает скрипт, который бесконечным циклом парсит некоторые данные и заносит их в БД. В прошлый раз когда я запускал скрипт, он поработал полчаса, а потом сервер выдал Interal Server Error и я не смог его вытащить, пришлось принимать радикальные меры в виде переустановки всего. Нужно ли (и как) настраивать сервер для подобных задач (не считая execution time в php.ini)?

Comment: Дополните ваш вопрос описанием ошибки из лога и конфигурацией nginx. Следите ли вы за расходом памяти, во время выполнения парсинга?

Comment: @LANSELOT у меня не осталось логов, увы. Я всё удалил. Но тогда у меня был apache и ошибка была с mod_fcgid, и ни один из способов решения, найденных в интернете, не помогли. В итоге я поменял сервер на nginx (мне на нём привычнее). Теперь вопрос в том, нужно ли как-то дополнительно настраивать сервер, а остальное не столь важно.

Comment: @DeFF Я вот не понял, как у вас мог не поднятся сервер после internal error. Ну предположим сожрал весь скрипт память или занял все место на диске. Перестали работать скрипты... Но система после перезагрузки все равно даст по крайней мере войти и посмотреть что случилось. Так что можно сказать что должно было случится что то более серьезное

Comment: @Mike система дала войти, но ничего не помогало разобраться с этим. В итоге я отчаялся. Я уверен, что выход был, но у меня нет столько времени чтобы искать ответ. Тем более я давно хотел заменить apache на nginx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все скриптовые языки текут по памяти, особенно PHP. Т.е. берут память и не возвращают в систему, уже хорошо, если они возвращают память в кучу процесса. Однако, сам процесс может разрастаться. Посмотрите не увеличивается ли объем потребляемой памяти (99% что увеличивается). Не могло получиться так, что скрипт забрал критическую долю ресурсов?

Поэтому, обычно, скрипты запускают на короткое время. Возможно, здесь так же стоит перезапускать скрипт, например, по cron-заданию, если есть такая возможность.

Comment: А вы правы. Это раньше я не знал точного время выполнения скрипта и не использовал крон. Теперь всё стало яснее. После завершения выполнения php вернёт память?

Comment: Вот и говорите про php. про "все" скриптовые - это как то перебор. У меня месяцами без перезапуска крутятся перловые скрипты и как то не увеличиваются ...

Comment: Да, после завершения процесса, система заберет всю память, выделенную под процесс.

Comment: Про "все" я наверное действительно погорячился, но большинство течет. Ruby, PHP точно. Последние движения в обоих с попытками заморозить строки связаны конечно, больше со скоростью выполнения, но это и способ устранить утечки памяти.

Comment: Если конечно, у вас новые объекты не создаются, рано или поздно скрипт "насытится" - если ничего не делать, ничего и не происходит. Однако, это не всегда возможно.